# How to change host name before first boot?

Tags: raspbian, ssh, headless

Is it possible to change the host name before the first boot?  I've tried changing the name in `/etc/hostname`, but then the Pi doesn't boot properly.  Is there something else that needs to be done?

This is intended for a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian/Raspberry Pi OS (lite) that is headless and connected by Ethernet.  I'd like to be able to connect to the Raspberry Pi using `ssh`.  (I have verified that if I don't change the host name I am able connect with `ssh`.)

Comment: *"then the Pi doesn't boot properly."* -> This shouldn't happen, methinks, but oh well.  Have a look at `man 5 hostname` and the suggestion about using `systemd-firstboot` (then read `man systemd-firstboot`); the idea is that you mount the root filesystem somewhere (with systemd available) and use that to tweak the image without having to run the system in it.  If it works out, please leave an answer of your own!

Comment: You need to change /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To translate the script from *Milliways* in his answer, change the name in `/etc/hostname` as you already have done and add or change the entry `127.0.1.1    raspberrypi` in `/etc/hosts` to the new hostname.

Comment: there is no dir `etc` in the sd root. only `overlays`

Comment: "Is it possible to change the host name before the first boot?" - does the /etc exist before first boot?

Answer (score 8):

If someone is still looking in this thread,
you are now able to change the hostname (among other initial settings) from the Pi Imager before writing your boot drive.

To enable **Pi Imager advanced settings** before writing; press **ctrl + shift + X** while the Pi Imager is open.

This will bring the advanced menu where you are able to set up Hostname, SSH, Overscan, WiFi, Password, timezone etc.

These features came with the release of Pi Imager v1.6:
[Pi Imager v1.6 news](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-imager-update-to-v1-6/)

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible on a Linux computer (which can be a Pi)

The following code fragment is from one of my scripts; depending on how you implement this paths etc would need to be set.

```
CURRENT_HOSTNAME=$(cat /etc/hostname)

if [ $NEW_HOSTNAME = $CURRENT_HOSTNAME ]; then
    echo "Name already set"
else
    echo "Setting Name" $NEW_HOSTNAME
    echo $NEW_HOSTNAME > /etc/hostname
    sed -i "/127.0.1.1/s/$CURRENT_HOSTNAME/$NEW_HOSTNAME/" /etc/hosts
fi
```

You are unlikely to find any existing code, but if I wanted to do this I would loop mount the image and edit it.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this answer on [insidedarkweb](https://insidedarkweb.com/raspberry-pi/how-to-set-the-hostname-via-boot-config-before-first-boot/) and thought I'd post it here. I ended up not needing to configure raspberry pi nodes prior to boot since I am running a configuration script afterwards anwyas.

Use a soft symlink to configure the SD card (for command line, otherwise use the GUI from the answer above):

```
rpi ~$ sudo bash -c 'echo <desired hostname> /boot/hostname'
rpi ~$ sudo ln -s /boot/hostname /etc/hostname

rpi ~$ sudo bash -c 'echo \'127.0.0.1 <desired hosname>\' >> /boot/hostname'
rpi ~$ sudo ln -s /boot/hosts /etc/hosts
```